# Set.value replaces existing data with new one

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to write some values to the firebase database but when a new value is written the old value gets deleted?

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId).child("Messages");
        DatabaseReference userref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
        userref.setValue(Username);
        DatabaseReference keyReference = databaseReference.push();
        User user=new User("Mine message is here","Sender");
       keyReference.setValue(user);
```

Comment: Use `updateChildren()` instead of `setValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you shared you call `DatabaseReference.push()`. Each time you call `push`, Firebase generates a key for a new unique location. So if you then call `setValue` on that new reference, you're writing a brand new value.

---

The `setValue` method always replaces whatever is at the `DatabaseReference` with the value that you provided. But since there isn't any value at the new location, you're just writing an entirely new user.

If you want to **update** an existing node without replacing existing values, you either have to call `setValue()` on a lower-node, or call `updateChildren()`.

For example to update a `username` property under `/Users/$userId/username`, you can do:

```
userref.child("username").setValue("New username");
```

This will leave any other child node under `/Users/$userId` unmodified.

If you want to update multiple children under `/Users/$userId`, you can either call `setValue` multiple times:

```
userref.child("username").setValue("New username");
userref.child("location").setValue("San Francisco");
```

Or you can put the values into a `Map` and pass that into `updateChildren`:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("username", "New username");
values.put("location", "San Francisco");
userref.updateChildren(values);
```

Comment: Does it some thing to do with the fact that I have 2 data base reference declared. When i remove the first declaration i.e. userref it just updates fine

Comment: If you remove `userref`, then `userref.setValue(Username);` will fail. But honestly: I wasn't really sure what you're trying to accomplish, and what you're seeing instead, which is why I explained a few ways to accomplish common use-cases.